# installed create-react-app without -g

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, create-react-app

I have installed `create-react-app` without `-g`

`C:\Users\user1\projects\react>npm install create-react-app`

but when I run

`C:\Users\user1\projects\react>create-react-app my-app1`

I get the following error

`'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

can anyone please help me understand the role of `-g` flag

what if I dont want to install it globally?

How do I make it work without installing globally?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I don't want to install it globally.

Comment: If you use `-g` flag for `npm install`, the package will be installed **globally**. That enables you to use them as commands in the command line. Without the flag you would have to use them like `node_modules/create-react-app/bin my-app1`

Answer (score 7):

> what if I dont want to install it globally?
>
> How do I make it work without installing globally?

The package is *designed* to be installed globally. Please use it as intended.

If you don't want to permanently install it, in recent Node versions you can actually run it without installing through `npx`:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Just a quick reminder that you could install [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) as a separate module for previous node versions

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed any `npm` module locally it will be stored in the `.bin` folder inside `node_modules`. To use this, you would have to reference `node_modules/.bin/the binary to run`. If installed globally, the module's binary will be stored wherever your OS stores executables that are run from the terminal, in Unix/Linux, for instance, it's usually something like `/usr/bin`(not absolutely sure). This is why installing something locally won't run by simply typing out its name in the terminal. Rather reference it absolutely like this `node_modules/bin/the binary to run`.

Comment: tried running `C:\Users\user1\projects\react>node_modules/.bin/create-react-app my-app1` got this `'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`